# When you use scanf in C to receive a Korean string value, store it in a variable, and output it, a blank space appears

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote a code to write and print a name using `scanf` in C, but when I input Korean into `scanf`, a space is output.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[50];
    printf("what your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s!", name);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
what your name? 한국어
hello,  !
```

I expected:

```
what your name? 한국어
hello, 한국어!
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the output you claim to get. Please [edit] your question to make sure both the code and the input and output is copy-pasted correctly.

Comment: Besides that, with the code you show [I can't replicate the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/3ahfxP67o). What are your terminal settings? How do you build? How do you run? And generally, *always* check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value). And add a limit to the input format so you don't risk overwriting the buffer: Change `scanf("%s", name)` to `scanf("%49s", name)`.

Comment: As Someprogrammerdude has mentioned, this is probably environmental.  On a hunch, I would guess the font you are using in the terminal just does not have those characters in them.